# How to directly link to the Firefox Add-On Keyboard Shortcuts page

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am building a WebExtension on Chrome and Firefox which performs task X, Y and Z through a popup (browser_action).

I would like to allow users to trigger X, Y and Z through keyboard shortcuts using the [commands API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/commands). Keyboard shortcuts must be configured directly in the browser (as opposed to your own extension's settings page) to prevent overlap of shortcuts across multiple extensions.

On Chrome I can link directly to the keyboard shortcuts page, from my extension's settings page, using this method:

```
chrome.tabs.update({ url: 'chrome://extensions/shortcuts' });
```

For Firefox, I have to go to `about:addons` and then click on the gear icon in the top right and then click `Manage Extension Shortcuts`. This is not very straightforward IMO and I would prefer to be able to link directly to this page.

Is there a fixed url I can use to navigate directly to the keyboard shortcuts page in Firefox?

Comment: There's no such URL so you can suggest implementing it on their bugtracker.

Comment: Yeah I had a feeling this would be the case. Could not find an open issue for this in bugzilla which is why I asked the question here in case I was missing something obvious. I guess I will just include instructions for the user to navigate themselves to the Keyboard Shortcuts page if they are using Firefox

Comment: There is an existing bug with some recent activity: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1538451